# Jquery - why is click() and .on("click") triggering twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this getting triggered twice on click? It isn't calling any external functions. The result is that the offState gets triggered twice, negating its purpose. Does click() fire twice by default? I also tried `.on('click', function()...` with the same results.

```
function makeBackNav(){
    $('.backTitle').text("");
        //make back button's text the previously selected category
        $('.backTitle').append(prevLocation).click(function(){
            //need to swap images around so that they are activated on click
                var onState = $('#' + selectedCategory).find('img').first().attr('src');
                var offState = $('#' + selectedCategory).find('img').last().attr('src');
            $('#' + selectedCategory).find('img').last().attr('src', onState);
            console.log(offState);          
        });
}
```

Comment: How often do you call `makeBackNav()`? Each time you call it it will bind an additional click handler, not replace any previous click handler. Then when the element is actually clicked all click handlers will be called.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I just called an `.off("click")` before each `.on()` binding.